# (JS) How to use the "new" operator and return something other than "this"?

Tags: javascript, new-operator

I am making a JavaScript game framework. I have a function called `Color3`. I am trying to use the function using the `new` operator. However, every time it returns the object instead of the string I wanted to return. Here is the code:

```
Color3 = function(r, g, b) {
    this.r = 255;
    this.g = 255;
    this.b = 255;

    if (r != null)
        this.r = r;
    if (g != null)
        this.g = g;
    if (b != null)
        this.b = b;

    return "rgb(" + this.r + ", " + this.g + ", " + this.b + ")";
};

var myColor = new Color3(0, 255, 0);
console.log(myColor);
```

Expected output:

```
"rgb(0, 255, 0)"
```

Actual output:

```
Color3 {r: 0, g: 255, b: 0}
```

Is there a way that I can get the expected output? Or do I have to not use the `new` operator?

Comment: Why do you want a constructor at all?!?

Comment: `new` is to instantiate an object, not to call a function.

Comment: You have to not use the `new` operator. Why would you want to use the `new` operator in the first place if you don't want your function to return a newly instantiated object? You're using `this` as if you want to do something with an object, but if `new` didn't return it you wouldn't have any references to that object anyway so it would just be eligible for garbage collection.

Comment: This sounds like an XY problem.

Comment: `s/this\.//g` `s/new //g` would solve your issue...

Comment: @CertainPerformance Especially the fifth bullet point in [this answer on MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/233676/152692).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If what you return is not an object, the default object is returned. You should return an object to change the return value. Try return `new String("rgb(" + this.r + ", " + this.g + ", " + this.b + ")")`

Comment: Thanks! This one worked perfectly. But why should I not use it?

Comment: because it will make harder for people to understand your intentions. If you want to return a color from an object, create 2 separate functions, one for the object, the other that takes that object and extracts r,g,b. But you know its your thing, do it as you like.

Comment: @Tunacan a constructor is used to *create* new objects of the type you want. What you want is to simply call the function normally. Changing how the constructor operates for such a trivial thing is bad practice.

Comment: Because the wrapper objects are completely crap. You should never ever use them at all. They are only there for consistency.

Comment: @vlaz If you call the constructor without `new` it doesn't get a `this` object.

Comment: @Tunacan The only possible reason to ever want to do this is to make your code harder to read. There is no legitimate reason to construct a new object and immediately discard it like this.

Comment: @Barmar that's true, but it's not like OP is actually using `this` for any real purpose. Removing it will have no impact on the functionality.

Answer (score 3):

The return value is only returned if it is an object. If you return a primitive (number, boolean, string, `undefined`, `null`), the object constructed is returned.

You can **probably** return a `String` object:

```
return new String("rgb(" + this.r + ", " + this.g + ", " + this.b + ")");
```

This will **probably** work, though there are some differences between string primitives and string objects.

The more important questions is "why do you *want* to do this?" It doesn't seem like you actually want to construct an object at all (you're discarding the one you construct): a plain old function would work just fine.

Answer (score 1):

> *"Is there a way that I can get the expected output? Or do I have to not use the new operator?"*

Yes, you can construct objects like that and still get the expected output. You do this by adding a `.toString()` method to the `.prototype` of the constructor.

```js
Color3 = function(r, g, b) {
    if (r != null)
        this.r = r;
    if (g != null)
        this.g = g;
    if (b != null)
        this.b = b;
};

Color3.prototype.r = 255;
Color3.prototype.g = 255;
Color3.prototype.b = 255;

Color3.prototype.toString = function() {
  return "rgb(" + this.r + ", " + this.g + ", " + this.b + ")";
}

var c = new Color3(123, 234, 345);
console.log(`Color is: ${c}`);
```

I also added the default RGB values to the prototype.

Comment: I think this is what the OP really wants to do.

Answer (score 0):

The `new` method for Javascript contructors creates a "new" instance of an Object specified by the constructor. You would need to do something like this:

```
Color3 = function(r, g, b) {
    this.r = 255;
    this.g = 255;
    this.b = 255;

    if (r != null)
        this.r = r;
    if (g!= null)
        this.g = g;
    if (b != null)
        this.b = b;

    this.getColor = function(){
      return "rgb(" + this.r + ", " + this.g + ", " + this.b + ")";
    }
};
var someColor = Color3.new(200,200,200);
someColor.getColor();
```

Comment: You're missing the definition of `newColor()`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to return the string that Color3 returns, you should call Color3 function with out the 'new' operator:

```js
Color3 = function(r, g, b) {
    this.r = 255;
    this.g = 255;
    this.b = 255;

    if (r != null)
        this.r = r;
    if (g != null)
        this.g = g;
    if (b != null)
        this.b = b;

    return "rgb(" + this.r + ", " + this.g + ", " + this.b + ")";
};

var color =  Color3(8,22,3);

//testing the Color3 function
console.log(typeof(color));
console.log(color);
```

Comment: What is `this.r` if there's no object being constructed?

Answer (score 0):

Is that what you are after?

```
Color3 = function(r, g, b) {
    this.r = 255;
    this.g = 255;
    this.b = 255;
    this.rgb;

    if (r != null)
        this.r = r;
    if (g != null)
        this.g = g;
    if (b != null)
        this.b = b;

    this.rgb = this.r + ", " + this.g + ", " + this.b ;

};

var myColor = new Color3(0, 255, 0);
console.log(myColor.rgb);
```